# binary file encryption problem

Tags: c++, file, binary, xor

i'm having a problem while encrypting some data in the file. i'm using simple xor for that.
lets say i have this struct:

```
struct MyFile{
char fileName[128];
int account;
float balance;};
```

saving this as a binary file is working properly but when i use xor to encrypt the filename in the struct and save the struct to hd then reading the struct and decrypting the filename is not showing the characters correctly. i'm using this simple function for the encryption/decryption purpose.

```
static void Codec(const char *key,int keySize,char* in,char *result,int length)  
{
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        result[i]=in[i]^key[i%keySize];
}
```

Note that when i encrypt the filename and directly decrypt it in memory the result is right. what am i missing like why is it being changed when saved on the hard disk. please reply asap and tnx in advance...

Comment: You can't really use the 'encryption' tag when asking about an XOR question... It takes just about 0.0001 seconds for any bloke to figure out your 'key'.

Comment: How are you writing/reading the file? And @ Remus, it seems like he's using a one time pad, since his code is using a stream of keys. That's technically secure as long as he doesn't reuse the key. EDIT: oh unless he is using a key shorter than the file. Then yeah, it's going to be ridiculously easy to figure out

Comment: Try xor'ing it with zeros for the key -- is your algo working?

Comment: Are you assuming a NULL terminated fileName, then removing the NULL with the encryption?

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: This exactly what envcryption means. Yes XOR is simple. But given a good one time pad key it will hold up against most (not governments but individuals) abrute forcing. See how long this takes (converted each char into int so I could post it): "37 31 12 1 84 16 6 73 14 30 65 22 10 5 21 17 26 31 19 23 13 86 22 11 30 53 97 53 46 97 50 101 20 87 12 20 84 0 26 28 79 19 0 29 68 2 2 11 5 15 31 88 10 2"

Comment: Make sure that the when you read and write the file it is opened in binary mode. When in text mode the EOL sequence is convered to/from "\r\n". If this happens it may shift the string in relation to the key and thus cause the de-cryption to fail.

Comment: @Martin York: XOR a 'good pad' is basically a stream cipher, like RC4. So beter use a stream cipher and properly encrypt the data. apparently benign phrases like 'a good one time pad' hide a devilish complexity in them. How is the 'one time pad' generated? A good 'one time pad' generator *is* a stream cipher algorithm. And not to mention the further questions like wher eis it stored between usages? Any reuse and a crib will reveal it (if I know the file contains *Keine besonderen Ereignisse* at offset 12 etc...)

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: It all depnds on the audiance from who you want to protect against. If it is a government/Multinational corp etc nothing but the latest algo with a generated key is going to work. If I am protecting against "Bob and Sons" down the road or my brother XOR will be fine.

Comment: @Martin: I don't understand these comments about "not good enough for a government/multinational corp". If the data is truly random (as in theory data is from a hardware random number generator) the encryption is PERFECT provided the key is perfectly secure. Without the key, the cipher text is completely meaningless. The only weakness is when the "random key" isn't really random and a pattern can be computed.

Comment: @Andrew Flanagan: I am just implying that big agencies have enough resources to brute force an attack against simple schemes. I am implying nothing about the goodness or badness of the encryption. Book cypher are stil my favorite as the key is basically humungess.

Comment: @Martin York:  And what Andrew pointed out is that a one-time pad is absolute security, provided the key is random and the bad guys don't get a copy.  Brute-forcing an attempt on a N-byte string will result in every possible N-byte string, with no way of telling which is the correct one.

Comment: @David Thornley, @Andrew Flanagan: Which is why I say in my first comment I question Remus assertations why he thinks it is not encryption. XOR with a key is relatively strong and without significant resources is not going to be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you need to open the files in binary mode ("rb"/"wb" instead of "r"/"w" for `fopen`). Windows C implementations in particular have problems regarding `\n`<->`\r\n` conversion.

It is also a good idea to use `unsigned char`s for arithmetic and bitwise operations; anything but 8-bit two's complement signed chars might cause trouble (which, granted, most implementations use and might not cause any trouble with symmetric XOR encryption, but it's still good to be careful.)

Answer (score 2):

First, determine whether the data is actually being altered when it is written to the disk.  Have your program print out the string in these four places:

1. Before encrypting it
2. After encrypting it but before writing it to the disk
3. After reading it from the disk but before decrypting it
4. After decrypting it

Are the results from #2 and #3 the same?  If so, then the file is not being changed during the transfer to disk and back.

If #2 and #3 are different, try writing the unencrypted string to disk and reading it back out.  Does this work successfully?

Write only a single such structure to a file and examine the contents of the file in a hex editor.  What does the file look like while it is on the disk?

Post your write-to-disk and read-from-disk code as well, part of the problem may lie there.

Answer (score 2):

You must open the file in binary mode. If you use C I/O (like I normally do) this means

```
FILE *input_file = fopen(input_file_name, "rb");
FILE *output_file = fopen(output_file_name, "wb");
```

If instead you've been tricked into using C++ streams this means

```
std::ifstream input_file(input_file_name, ios::in | ios::binary);
std::ofstream output_file(output_file_name, ios::out | ios::binary);
```